# Upload an image using alamofire swift

Tags: ios, swift3

> ```
>             self.manager!.request( RestApiManager.sharedInstance.baseURL+"rest/secure/add/"+self.id!+"/create?language="+lang, method: .post, parameters: requestDictionary, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,headers: headers
>                 ).responseObject(keyPath: "") { (response: DataResponse<User>) in
> ```

This is how I call my post method, however I need to add image file uploaded as well with it. Entity part called uploadFile.How this be done ?

> ```
> entity.addPart("uploadFile", new FileBody(f100));
>
>
>  let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagetoadd.image!)
> ```

I want to upload an image , with parameters heading as well like username  - john and headers, plus i want to get dataresponse type user ( mapped to)

am trying sthg like this in swift 3, its not working.

> ```
>              self.manager!.upload(.post,RestApiManager.sharedInstance.baseURL+"rest/secure/stores/"+self.id!+"/create?language="+lang,
>                                  // define your headers here
>                 multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in                      
>                     // import image to request
>                     if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
>                         multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: image_data, name: "uploadFile", fileName: nameOfImage+".png", mimeType: "image/png")
>                     }                
>                     // import parameters
>                     for (key, value) in parameters {
>                         multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
>                     }
>             }, // you can customise Threshold if you wish. This is the alamofire's default value
>                 encodingMemoryThreshold: manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
>                 encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
>                     switch encodingResult {
>                     case .Success(let upload, _, _):
>                         upload.responseJSON { response in
>                             debugPrint(response)
>                         }
>                     case .Failure(let encodingError):
>                         print(encodingError)
>                     }
>             },headers: headers)
>         }
> ```

Missing argument using trashold in call.Am using latest alamofire library

Answer (score 0):

```
func uploadImageInDatabase(image:UIImage)
{
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4)
    let url = "Your server url"
    let date = NSDate()
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yy-hh-mm-ss"

    let imageName = df.string(from: date as Date)
    print(imageName)

     SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading")

            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                 multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "uploadedfile", fileName: "\(imageName).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }, to: url) { (encodingResult) in


                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):

                        upload.responseJSON{
                            response in

                            if let data = response.result.value{
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    if(response.response?.statusCode == 200){
                                        //callback(true, JSON(data), JSON((response.response?.statusCode)!))
                                        let Data = data as! NSDictionary
                                        showAlert(message: Data["msg"]as! NSString)

                                        self.ImageURL = Data["data"]as! String
                                        print(self.ImageURL)
                                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                                    } else{
                                        //callback(false, JSON(data), JSON((response.response?.statusCode)!))
                                        print(data)
                                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        print(encodingError)
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            //callback(false,JSON(self.getStatusCodeString(408)),JSON(408))
                        }

    }


    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation & formatting to that?

Comment: its just a function in wihch you have to pass image which you want uplaod.It upload your image using multipart of alamofire